# TCB Enabled During Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, aix

I'm pretty sure I know the answer to this, but I wouldn't be doing my due diligence if I didn't ask: I know that you can only enable TCB in AIX during install, but what about during an upgrade? Can you enable TCB during the upgrade of AIX from, say, 5.3 to 7.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM support might be the most official answer you can get; short of calling them, I would refer to [Installing the Trusted Computing Base (TCB) on AIX 6.1 and 7.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1011958) where it says, in part:

> TCB cannot be added or enabled on a system that has already been installed. It can only be chosen when AIX is first installed.

Given that one of the requirements is to choose `New and Complete Overwrite` as the Method of Installation, I would assume that no, it is not possible during an upgrade.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I just needed someone else to confirm what I already knew. Thanks.